# Extremely New to Python, Need Selenium Webdriver to check checkboxes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my first post. I am trying to learn basic programming to be able to better communicate with developers working for my company on a completely separate project.

I was doing some house-keeping of the company's facebook page and wanted to run a script with Selenium webdriver coded in Python to help me quickly check multiple checkboxes on the facebook "peoples" page.

I've gotten pretty far into the script except for being able to target and check off the boxes needed.

Please advise on how I can target and select the checkboxes, and go down the row to continuously do that for a specified amount of boxes.

Here's where I'm at:

```
import time
import selenium.webdriver.support.wait

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path='C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/eddiejagmedia/settings/?tab=people_and_other_pages&ref=page_edit")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']").send_keys("email")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass']").send_keys("pass")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'u_0_')][@value='Log In']").click()

element: object = selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "ContentPlaceHolder1_wucSignInStep2_chkTC")))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

This is the HTML code of the checkboxes, not sure which parent I'm supposed to grab though.

```
<label class="_55sg _kv1"><input name="select_single_row_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="100003109554020"><span class="_66ul"></span></label>
```

Lastly, here is a picture of what it looks like to help imagine the scope.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxsZb.jpg)

Thank you so much,
Eduardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_wucSignInStep2_chkTC")))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Following your advice, I modified to find By.CSS_SELECTOR.

This worked. I was able to click the first checkbox. Is there a way to automate it going down the row instead of having to add each CSS selector?

Comment: I was able to locate the element now by XPATH too. Just wondering how I can make a loop to check 10, scroll down, check another 10. For a defined number

Comment: Yes, I need url to respond you back & url provided in that question is not working for me

Comment: the URL goes to inside the settings of a company page managed by me. That's why it's very difficult for me to demonstrate to you. The best I can do is a screenshot and as much HTML as possible